# Why this cron pattern doesn't match/run every 37 seconds?

Tags: spring, cron, spring-scheduled

I have a Spring app with this property:

```
cobra.tarifas.intervaloEntreCobrancas =*/37 * * * * *
```

And this is where it's used:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${cobra.tarifas.intervaloEntreCobrancas}")
public void cobraTarifaDMaisZero() {

    int number = new Random().nextInt();

    System.out.println("started " + number + " at " + LocalTime.now().withNano(0));
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("finished " + number + " at " + LocalTime.now().withNano(0));
}
```

So every time it runs I have a log that points out when it started and finished, along with a "unique" identifier (Spring uses same instance at `@Scheduled` classes with no extra configuration, `this.toString` returned same string everytime). Every execution takes 5 seconds to complete.

I thought that cron expression meant "runs everytime every 37 seconds" but it didn't.

Using `* * * * * *` I got this:

```
started -1615036471 at 10:18:46
finished -1615036471 at 10:18:51
started 2090620070 at 10:18:52
finished 2090620070 at 10:18:57
started -349207943 at 10:18:58
finished -349207943 at 10:19:03
```

Which made sense: it takes 1s to start a new execution after a previous one was finished, always taking 5s to complete. But when I used `*/37 * * * * *` I got

```
started -644623959 at 10:54
finished -644623959 at 10:54:05
started 212117957 at 10:54:37
finished 212117957 at 10:54:42
started 1788724609 at 10:55
finished 1788724609 at 10:55:05
started 362510867 at 10:55:37
finished 362510867 at 10:55:42
started -25103618 at 10:56
finished -25103618 at 10:56:05
started -820939074 at 10:56:37
finished -820939074 at 10:56:42
```

Why it's starting only at seconds 00 and 37? I wanted to implement a similar behavior as Spring's `@fixedDelay` but flexible to be changed at some properties file(`@fixedDelay` only accept constants).

Comment: That is why there is a `fixedDelayString` property to hold an expression. Also it means (if I translate correctly) run every `37th second` not run every `37 seconds`.

Comment: @Todd I'm running again to check this, certainly I mistakenly edited along with comments

Comment: @M.Deinum, does cron expressions offer support to statements like `every 37 seconds` instead of `every 37th second`?

Comment: @M.Deinum, I understood your comment just now. If you want, could you please state your first comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that you can actually do this only with cron, for a number such as 37.

The easiest option, would be to select an increment that can divide 60.
Basically an even number that is equal to ( or less than) 30.

E.g. So 10, 15, 20, or 30.

For 10, your expression would be:

```
cobra.tarifas.intervaloEntreCobrancas =0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * *
```

Otherwise, you could just go for once per minute.

```
0 * * * * *
```